# Fullpage slides infinite scroll

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

Is it possible with fullPage.js plugin to have an end to the horizontal scrolls of the slides? I mean if I have lets say 3 slides (left, middle, right) is it possible to do that when you are on the left side, left arrow disappears and you have to go back to the middle slide. Same thing for the right slide.

Comment: Yes, It is very possible. If you provided some code I'd show you how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your options, override the default:

```
loopHorizontal = true;
```

Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        loopHorizontal: false
    });
});
```

Additional options can be found at the documentation site:

https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#usage

Comment: If this answered your question properly please feel free to check the green check-box next to the answer provided.

Comment: Great that's exactly what i was looking for